# Cron job to delete records from mongo db collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with below record structure:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6038930b613474692f48f81e"
  },
  "sender_id": "default",
  "active_form": {},
  "followup_action": null,
  "latest_action_name": "action_listen",
  "latest_event_time": 1614320506.277497,
  "latest_input_channel": "cmdline",
  "paused": false
}
```

I want to delete all the records which have `latest_event_time` which are older than 2 years from now as part of a cron job running at regular intervals. I cannot update the data types for these fields now. The data type for `latest_event_time` is double and it stores the timestamp value. How can I approach this problem to delete all the records by comparing `latest_event_time` field timestamp values.

Comment: Would you consider creating an auxiliary field which contains `$toDate` result from `latest_event_time`? If you created such auxiliary field, you can then create [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#ttl-indexes) to automatically remove your documents too.

Comment: The TTL index is not suitable for this use case since it's not a one-time activity. We need to run this job periodically to delete records

Comment: I think TTL index will delete records automatically instead of a one-time behaviour. Nevertheless, you may also create the mentioned auxiliary field and run your cron job based on filtering on the auxiliary field.

Comment: I tried adding the $toDate to the aggregate function but the given dates are not getting converted to the right ISO dates.

Comment: From your sample document, your latest_event_time seems to be in seconds. You will need to multiply by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds before using $toDate

Comment: [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kC6mkT4Ecla) for your reference

Comment: If we multiply the current latest_event_time with 1000 and update it in the same document it should work for me but, I am not able to come up with a query for the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235409/discussion-between-abhilash-and-ray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to purge old records was by using the aggregate function to convert latest_event_time to date format and then collect it. We are then deleting all such records at once.

```
var today = new Date();
var requiredDay = new Date(today.getTime() - (150*24*60*60*1000));
var idsList = db.conversations.aggregate([
    {
     $addFields: {
       my_event_time: { "$toDate": {
          "$multiply": [
            "$latest_event_time",
            1000
          ]
        }}
     }
   },
    { $match: { my_event_time: { $lt: requiredDay } } }
  ]).map(function(d) {
    return d._id;
  });


db.conversations.remove({ _id: { $in: idsList } });
```