# Mongodb - Delete document automatically after one month once trash field change to true

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I want to keep user "deleted" document for next one month in db and then it should be deleted  automatically

```
let product = new Schema({
      name: String,
      trash: false
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);




let task = { $set: { trash: true };

   removeDoc = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(query, task, {new: true });
```

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546830/cron-job-to-delete-records-from-mongo-db-collection

Comment: Believe that you should need a [Scheduled Trigger](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/triggers/scheduled-triggers/#create-a-scheduled-trigger)

Comment: I disagree that you need the (relative) complexity from the other two comments. You can do this directly in the database with an index that is both TTL and partial (with the condition that `trash: true`)